# How to reference the page of a figure?

Tags: cross-referencing, floats

Is it possible to make a reference to the page where a figure is rendered?

I would like to write something like

```
see figure~\ref{figure-xyz} on page NN
```

where NN will automatically be maintained by LaTeX. The figure that prompted my question is almost a page so it may be floated further in the doc.

I suppose it's possible, after all the figure-to-page mapping is generated by `\listoffigures`.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
see figure~\ref{figure-xyz} on page~\pageref{figure-xyz}
```

Also see the [`varioref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package which lets you write `see figure~\vref{figure-xyz}` which will automatically add the "on page NN" iff the figure is not on the current page.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I didn't know about the varioref package, it's very handy.

Comment: Note: according to variosref documentation, you do not need to add unbreakable space `~` before `\vref`. Any ordinary space will be converted into an unbreakable space.

Answer (score 34):

Just use `\pageref{}`, so in your case:

```
see figure \ref{figure-xyz} on page \pageref{figure-xyz}
```

Comment: Please do not omit the `~`. Without it, it could happen, that `figure` is placed at the end of the line and the number `\ref{}` at the beginning of the next line. `~` inserts an unbreakable space so that the number can't be divided from `figure` which is good typography. Same for `~\cite` etc.

Comment: @Mensch I wish I had known that before!

Answer (score 5):

A quite complete solution for page references at package `cleveref` ([Cleveref documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)). You don't have to write "page" or "pages" when cross-referencing, neither "figure" or "figures" (!).

> if  you  want  a  page  reference,  use `\cpageref` (and  don’t  write
> “page”  in  front),  if  you  want  a  page  range,
> use `\cpagerefrange`, and if you want to refer to multiple pages, simply
> throw all your comma separated labels into a single `\cpageref`.

In your case, I would use `\cpageref{}` for the page and `\cref{}` for the figure itself, for example,

```
%At preamble
\usepackage{cleveref}

%...

see \cref{figure-xyz} on \cpageref{figure-xyz}
```

By the way, as an extra plus, you do not have to mind the `~` between `Figure` and `\ref`. All these issues are managed by the package =)