# How to get the page number where a Theorem appears?

Tags: page-numbering

I want to write an article where it will: "See the proof of Theorem 4.1 in the page ...". How can I access this page number in Latex?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/how-to-reference-the-page-of-a-figure

Comment: `\pageref{yourlabel}`, where `yourlabel` is the label for Theorem 4.1.